# How to conver the data in fromat of '3w 1d 4h' in hours coming from Jira in excel or python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to convert strings in format '3w 2d 1h' in mins but couldn't find a way to do it, neither in excel nor python. example data attached

[image: image 1]

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like [pytimeparse](https://github.com/wroberts/pytimeparse) (Install with `pip install pytimeparse`).

You can then easily convert your durations to minutes:

```py
from pytimeparse import parse

minutes = parse("3h 50m") / 60
print(minutes)
```

Output:

```
230.0
```